# How to create .NET CultureInfo with Dateformat ISO 8601?

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting, cultureinfo

Is it possible to make .NET create the following output?

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() --> "2017-11-07T00:40:00.123456Z"
```

Of course there is always the possibility to use ToString("s") or ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK"). But is there a way to adjust the default-behaviour for the parameterless ToString-Method to the desired output?

I tried changing the CurrentCulture. But the best I got was "2017-11-07 00:40:00.123456Z". I did not find a way to change the separator between the date and the time from a space to "T".

Comment: I guess to make the format with a space you did something like `c = new CultureInfo("en-US")
{
    DateTimeFormat =
    {
        ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd",
        LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.FFFK"
    }
}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible, but only by accessing an internal field via reflection, which is not guaranteed to work in all cases.

```
var culture = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
var field = typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo).GetField("generalLongTimePattern",
                                           BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (field != null)
{
    // we found the internal field, set it
    field.SetValue(culture.DateTimeFormat, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFK");
}
else
{
    // fallback to setting the separate date and time patterns
    culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFK";
}
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);  // "2017-11-07T00:53:36.6922843Z"
```

Note that the ISO 8601 spec *does* allow a space to be used instead of a `T`.  It's just *preferable* to use the `T`.

Comment: Thank you! I won't do that anyway since I do not feel comfortable using this.
Just if someone is interested: The field above is an internal "cache" for the datetime-format that is never modified.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformatinfo.cs,a1da93c5a4a8c4e3

Comment: Yeah, I'd recommend never actually doing this.  Just use `ToString` with a proper format specification.  Hiding it like this is probably not the best idea.  Maybe good in a pinch for a hacky workaround, but try to avoid it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Scott Hanselmann has blogged about it [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingEvilOverridingSystemDateTimesDefaultToString.aspx).

> a little Reflectoring shows us that the default format string for System.DateTime is "G" as in System.DateTime.ToString("G") where G is one of the presets.
>
> [...]
>
> And gets the output he expects, indicating that "G" is the **combination** of a **ShortDate** and a **LongTime**.

So you should override `ShortDatePattern` and `LongTimePattern`:

I converted the code to C# and yes, it is working:

```
var customCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US")
{
    DateTimeFormat =
    {
        ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd",
        LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFK"
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = customCulture;
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

Console.ReadLine();
```

However, Scott has titled his post **Enabling Evil** for reason. Think twice before doing that!

The `T` is not needed, but also can not be provided. If you still need it, you need to use Reflection, as [Matt answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47148246/2441442).